# how to remove the margin below a textarea inside a div wrapper (webkit)

Tags: webkit, textarea, wrapper, margin

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div style="background-color:#f09;">
           <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Result in Chrome:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Result in FF:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try display:block on the textarea:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <head>
      <style type="text/css">
           textarea {display:block;}
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div style="background-color:#f09;">
           <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The issue is that the textarea is inline and it is using the text height to add a bit of extra padding.  You can also specify:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div style="background-color:#f09;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;">
           <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Another option which is helpful if you want to keep the textarea inline and don't want to mess with the parent block's font properties (I suggest this over the previous method with line-height):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <head>
      <style type="text/css">
           textarea {vertical-align:middle;}
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div style="background-color:#f09;">
           <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Finally, if you're really worried about consistency between browsers keep in mind margins and other things like that can be defined with different defaults in different browsers.  Utilizing something like [YUI-Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) can help bring all new browsers to a consistent standard from which you can build.

Comment: If you want to keep the `<textarea>`'s `display` style inline, you can also use `textarea { vertical-align: bottom; }` (or `top`, or `middle`; probably pretty much any value other than `baseline`, which is the default for `inline` elements).

Comment: Thank god! Very nice. :)

Answer (score 9):

Setting the display mode to block did the trick for me. Just to clarify, here is the declaration that you need to add to your stylesheet. I would recommend adding it to your reset or normalize stylesheet, in the first place.

```
textarea {
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a "first line" in every global.css file I make.
saying:

```
<style>    
html,body,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,img,table,td,th 
{
   margin:0;padding:0;border:none;
   font-familiy:"my sites default font";font-size:10px;
}
</style>
```

After this, I feel that I have full control of the browsers behaviour, when testing on 5 different platforms: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and ... doh... Microsoft Internet Extracrap..

Then you can easily do something similar for < input > and < textarea > too.
if the first line does too much, then just make a second line for the "special cases" alone.

```
<style>
textarea {margin:0; padding:0; border:none; display:block;}
</style>
```

Remember that CSS inherits, so you can have multiple declarations of different classes.

Does this remove your problem?

Comment: I accept the -1 but please do comment who ever you are, so I know what you dont agree upon. It works for me, so I would like to know what I have missed.