# A div with a child textarea of the same size will overflow in chrome, only if the elements' height is set inline

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a fixed-height div containing a child textarea, also with a fixed height.

In chrome, if both the div and the textarea have the same height, the div will have a scrollbar (if set to overflow:auto ). That doesn't happen in firefox, and it doesn't happen either if you nest two div elements.

Here is a simple example:

```
<div style="height:100px; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto">
    <textarea style="height:100px; margin:0;padding:0;border:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut augue metus, pulvinar in accumsan ut, malesuada quis sapien. Curabitur eleifend massa ac arcu congue, eu aliquet enim porta. Integer tristique tristique placerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas elementum, arcu eget pulvinar sodales, quam metus pharetra felis, vel commodo enim eros a eros. Maecenas placerat ullamcorper odio, et viverra tellus tempor non. Proin iaculis non eros id convallis. Nullam tellus mauris, congue ut laoreet sit amet, mollis tempus lacus. Duis lacinia commodo convallis. Suspendisse mollis lectus a tristique mattis. Nullam gravida dictum purus a sagittis. Cras in sapien nec nulla porta consequat.
    </textarea>
</div>
```

In a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBn7Y/

If you replace the textarea element by a div with the same content and properties, the issue isn't present.

I would like to know why this is happening. Setting the overflow to hidden removes the div's scrollbar, but my particular case is a bit more complex, and hiding the overflow doesn't look very good.

My version of firefox is 24.0 and chrome is 29.0.1547.76, both running on linux mint 13. I have the same issue on chromium 28.0.1500.71

Thanks in advance to anyone with an explanation!

Edit:

Here is a screencap of the fiddle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ30V.png

I wish to remove the far right scrollbar, not the textarea's. It is indeed normal for the textarea to get a scrollbar since the text is long. What I don't understand is why does the parent div get a scrollbar too ?

The problem also only happens with inline style, if you set the size with classes the issue isn't happening. (example: http://jsfiddle.net/KPjak/ )

In my case, the height is set by javascript and is variable, so a class isn't a solution.

Comment: Do you want the height of the div to be determined based on the child elements?

Comment: You could still give it a class, and the only thing that class would determine would be whether or not the scrollbar is displayed or not.

Comment: Even if the scrollbar isn't displayed, the div is still scrollable, which is kind of weird (see http://jsfiddle.net/MBn7Y/4/ and try scrolling on the right of the textarea, it scrolls a few pixels up and down )

Comment: Removing overflow:auto; on the parent div stopped the scrolling. http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/MBn7Y/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the cause of all of this. There is a bug reported in webkit here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32731

The explanation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FElements%2Ftextarea):

> In regards to CSS, an `<textarea>` is a replaced element. The HTML specification doesn't define where the baseline of a `<textarea>` is. So different browsers set it to different positions. For Gecko, the `<textarea>` baseline is set on the baseline of the first line of the textarea's first line, on another browser it may be set on the bottom of the `<textarea>` box. Don't use vertical-align: baseline on it, as the behavior will be unpredictable.

A solution can be to set the textarea to display:block [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019645/1464027)

Or to set the parent's line-height to 0 [found here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32731#c5)

Thanks a lot to everyone helping me find the answer to this!

Answer (score 2):

I would say it has something to do with a bottom margin or padding with the textarea that's being applied outside of the css.  As to why this happens--no clue, ask your father.

It seems to be a 5% margin or padding.  See my fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/MBn7Y/6/

I widdled the height down by `%` until it didn't show the scrolls in the parent, came to 95%;

Last version shows `margin-bottom: -5%;` and works while matching full height of parent elements.

```
**CSS**
textarea {
    margin-bottom: -5% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the removal of a scrollbar by using the following snippet of CSS:

```
element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

I duplicated this within the following fiddle (had to replace some of the inline styles with classes): http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/MBn7Y/3/

Comment: I do not want to remove the textarea's scrollbar, I want to remove the parent div's scollbar

Comment: You can switch the classes around. (Updated the fiddle to reflect such)

Seems to work with Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

Comment: It's weird, your fiddle made me notice that the problem only appears with inline style. For example, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/KPjak/  while this: http://jsfiddle.net/MBn7Y/4/ doesn't really work ( the scrollbar is hidden, but you still can scroll a few pixels up and down with the wheel )